# Why is the statement "$\Gamma \cup \{ \phi \}$ is inconsistent and $\Gamma \cup \{ \neg \phi\}$ is inconsistent" a contradiction.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose $\Gamma$ is a maximal consistent set of sentences derived from set $\mathscr S$.

I need to demonstrate that the following two statements can not occur simultaneously:

$\Gamma \cup \{ \phi \}$ is inconsistent and $\Gamma \cup \{ \neg \phi\}$ is inconsistent.

It seems to me that I need to somehow show that if this were to be the case, then that means there exists a sequence of sentences belonging to or entailed by (which are the same in this case because $\Gamma$ is maximally consistent) $\Gamma$ such that upon the inclusion of either $\phi$ or $\neg \phi$ I can deduce any sentence $S \in \mathscr S$.

I'm guessing that in the construction of such a sequence (call it $\psi_1 \psi_2 ...\psi_n$), I arrive at a contradiction related to $\Gamma$ being maximally consistent. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to reveal this contradiction.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show that $\Gamma\cup\{\varphi\lor\neg\varphi\}$ is inconsistent and infer that $\Gamma$ is inconsistent.

Comment: Note that maximality plays no role here at all.

Comment: The statement $\Gamma \cup \{ \phi \}$ is a statement in the meta-theory :-) You can read it regarding the proof system you are working with: we can derive a contradiction (call it $\bot$) from it:  $\Gamma \cup \{ \phi \} \vdash \bot$, or you can read it regarding semantics: the set of formulas  $\Gamma \cup \{ \phi \}$ is *unsatisfiable*, i.e. (in prop logic) there is **no** valuation $v$ such that all the formulas in $\Gamma$ and $\phi$ con be evaluated TRUE by $v$.

Comment: The semantic side is quite easy to prove: assume that $\Gamma$ is consistent and consider a valuation $v$ that satisfies it.

Comment: The "proof-system" side needs (as per answer below) the resources of the proof system. But the Deduction Th. is (quite) always available, which means that (if both are inconsistent) $\Gamma \vdash \phi \to \bot$ and $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \phi \to \bot$. But $\phi \to \bot$ is equiv to $\lnot \phi$ while $\lnot \phi \to \bot$ is equiv to $\lnot \lnot \phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really just a special case of **proof by cases**:

> Suppose $\Gamma\cup\{\varphi\}\vdash\psi$ and $\Gamma\cup\{\neg\varphi\}\vdash\psi$. Then $\Gamma\vdash\psi$.

(In your question, take $\psi$ to be $\perp$: a theory is inconsistent iff it proves $\perp$.)

Depending on your proof system, this may be included explicitly as one of the basic inference rules. (Alternatively, you might deduce it by first using the deduction theorem to rewrite your hypotheses as $\Gamma\vdash\varphi\rightarrow\psi$ and $\Gamma\vdash\neg\varphi\rightarrow\psi$.)

Comment: I had some difficulty finding a reference to the claim "Suppose $\Gamma\cup\{\varphi\}\vdash\psi$ and $\Gamma\cup\{\neg\varphi\}\vdash\psi$. Then $\Gamma\vdash\psi$". But I came up with what I believe to be a tautology in the form $(\varphi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow \big((\neg \varphi \rightarrow \psi ) \rightarrow \psi \big )$, which I think proves it. Thus, given your suggested rephrasing of the hypothesis, you would necessarily prove that $\Gamma \vdash \bot$ (which is the contradiction we seek). Does that sound about right?

Comment: @S.Cramer It's going to depend on the specific system used, but for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#Inference_rules) the key step is $\vee L$ (together with a proof of $\Gamma\vdash\varphi\vee\neg\varphi$ and the cut rule). But yes, however you go about implementing proof by cases in your system this will be the conclusion.

Comment: Hah, I'm way too much of a novice to even recognize that multiple systems exist as opposed to just the sentential logic framework used in the book I am reading. Is there a a reason that $(\varphi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow \big((\neg \varphi \rightarrow \psi ) \rightarrow \psi \big )$ is not a tautology in other systems? Or is it that other systems have different deduction rules (i.e. perhaps in these other systems, tautologies are not automatically admitted...or the inference rule is slightly different)?